# All records not inserting into Mysql Table

Tags: mysql

Does mysql has a limit on how many records it can insert into a table?

I'm pulling records from an Oracle DB/Staff Table to a MySql Datbase/Staff Table by running a php script. The total records in the Oracle DB/Staff Table = 3602 after the script runs it only inserted 3319 records into the MySql/Staff Table.

Comment: Any warnings or errors?  MySQL tables are limited by the filesystem, but 3319 records is nothing!

Comment: have you checked your max_execution_time for php? see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

Comment: could you provide your code and some database schema?

Comment: Also, check [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html).

Comment: No warning or errors and I also set the max execution time in the php.ini from the default to 300= 5mins

Comment: create table staff_gymmembers_2012_2013
(
staff_id int(8) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
first_name varchar(65) NOT NULL,
last_name varchar(65) NOT NULL,
department varchar(255) NOT NULL,
job_title varchar(255) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB MAX_ROWS=5000;

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - how many rows can I insert in one single INSERT statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536103/mysql-how-many-rows-can-i-insert-in-one-single-insert-statement)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your table have some constraints like PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY which is causing some inserts to fail.

Check for warnings using following query after you execute INSERT as:

```
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

You can specify MAX_ROWS while creating a table.

Answer (score 0):

Check the 3320th row data in Oracle. If it is not compatible with MySQL because of special character the error may occur.

Comment: Hm lets discuss here with your warnings or data tuple.