# Can not MariaDB query with "Where not in" to work in laravel

Tags: laravel, mariadb, laravel-query-builder

I have a MariaDB query that runs fine in the database query.

```
SELECT student_id, last_name, first_name , Count(id) as courses FROM registrations
WHERE student_id NOT IN (SELECT student_id FROM exclude_from_tracking_list)
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
ORDER BY last_name
```

But can not get it to run in laravel 8.

```
DB::statement('with query')

DB::table('registrations') 
        ->selectRaw('student_id, last_name, first_name , Count(id) as courses')
        ->where(DB::raw('student_id NOT IN (SELECT student_id FROM exclude_from_tracking_list'))    
        ->groupBy('student_id')
        ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 3')
        ->orderBy('last_name')
        ->get();
```

What am I missing.   I've search and tried many other options.

But I keep getting this error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'is null group
> by `student_id` having COUNT(*) > 3 order by `last_name` asc' at line
> 1 (SQL: select student_id, last_name, first_name , Count(id) as
> courses from `registrations` where student_id NOT IN (SELECT
> student_id FROM exclude_from_tracking_list is null group by
> `student_id` having COUNT(*) > 3 order by `last_name` asc)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe next time you will format code correctly - check guidelines.. You can do something like this: `DB::table('registrations')
    ->selectRaw('student_id, last_name, first_name, Count(id) as courses')
    ->whereNotIn('student_id', function($query) {
        $query->select('student_id')->from('exclude_from_tracking_list');
    })
    ->groupBy('student_id')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 3')
    ->orderBy('last_name')
    ->get();`

Comment: Just as a side note; I don't know what the exact limit is for laravel but using `WHERE IN/NOT IN` usually has a max number of records (I think in Oracle it's around 1000 items, I see a SO post that says laravel has 1500) so depending on your needs, it may be better to change it to a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` or even a subquery to avoid the limits.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73170298/8678978

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message includes "is null" but there's nothing like that in the code you've shown. But, in general you should always aim to keep use of raw statements to a minimum. Something like this should be preferred, and may resolve the error you're seeing.

```php
$excluded = DB::table('exclude_from_tracking_list')->select('student_id');

$result = DB::table('registrations')
    ->select('student_id', 'last_name', 'first_name')
    ->selectRaw('count(id) as courses')
    ->whereNotIn('student_id', $excluded)
    ->groupBy('student_id')
    ->having('courses', '>', 3)
    ->orderBy('last_name')
    ->get();
```

See [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) on available query builder methods. For troubleshooting, replace `get()` with `toSql()` and inspect the output.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input.    I'm still learning mysql.