# MySQL Insert Statement xampp not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, phpmyadmin

Using XAMPP phpmyadmin SQL insert

So this is just a small portion of the entries I need to insert into the database. The statement works just fine if i insert 10-15 entries...but when I insert approximately 100 entries, I get this error:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line XXX

Where "XXX" is ALWAYS the last line. I've tried different entries and its always the last one. I've even taken those entries that say has an error, did a single insert statement - it works fine.

What am I doing wrong here? Why can't I insert 100 statements?

FYI - I set my php.ini file to have a max upload of 128M (default is 8M).

```
INSERT INTO `production_schedule` (                                                                                                                                                         
`ID`, `WO_NUM`, `WO_LINE`, `SALES_CCN`, `SO`, `SO_LINE`, `SO_DELIVERY`, `MAS_LOC`,`DUE_DATE`, `FGC`, `HPL`, `DESCRIPTION`, `AGC`, `DEL_TERM`, `ORDERED_QTY`, `CANC_QTY`, `TOT_SHIP_QTY`, `SCHED_DATE`, `CUS_LOC_NAME`, `PROMISE_DATE`, `BILL_TO_NAME`, `ITEM`, `ORDER_BALANCE`, `UNIT_COST`, `UNIT_PRICE`, `START_DATE`, `REQD_DATE`, `MFG_LINE`, `DATE_ADDED`, `HOUR_ADDED`, `DATE_UPDATED`, `HOUR_UPDATED`, `MODIFIED_BY`, `DATE_MODIFIED`, `PM_PLAN`, `PM_APPLICATIONS`, `PM_MECHANICAL`, `PM_ELECTRICAL`, `PM_DESIGN`, `PM_DETAIL`, `PM_PROGRAM`, `FOR_RECORD`, `OE_NA`, `OE_PLAN`, `OE_ACTUAL`, `APP_NA`, `APP_PLAN`, `APP_ACTUAL`, `APP_BY`, `ENG_START_NA`, `ENG_START_ACTUAL`, `ENG_START_BY`, `ENG_START_SAVED_BY`, `KICKOFF_NA`, `KICKOFF_PLAN`, `KICKOFF_ACTUAL`, `KICKOFF_BY`, `KICKOFF_SAVED_BY`, `SUB_OUT_NA`, `SUB_OUT_PLAN`, `SUB_OUT_ACTUAL`, `SUB_RET_PLAN`, `SUB_RET_ACTUAL`, `ME_ADV_REQ_NA`, `ME_ADV_REQ_PLAN`, `ME_ADV_REQ_ACTUAL`, `ME_ADV_REQ_BY`, `ME_ADV_REQ_SAVED_BY`, `EE_ADV_REQ_NA`, `EE_ADV_REQ_PLAN`, `MECH_REL_NA`, `MECH_REL_PLAN`, `MECH_REL_ACTUAL`, `MECH_REL_BY`, `MECH_REL_SAVED_BY`, `ELECT_REL_NA`, `ELECT_REL_PLAN`, `ELECT_REL_ACTUAL`, `ELECT_REL_BY`, `ELECT_REL_SAVED_BY`, `PROG_REL_NA`, `PROG_REL_PLAN`, `PROG_REL_ACTUAL`, `PROG_REL_BY`, `PROG_REL_SAVED_BY`, `REL_NA`, `REL_PLAN`, `REL_ACTUAL`, `REL_BY`, `REL_SAVED_BY`, `PROG_NA`, `PROG_PLAN`, `PROG_ACTUAL`, `PROG_BY`, `PROG_SAVED_BY`, `PUNCH_NA`, `PUNCH_PLAN`, `WING_NA`, `WING_PLAN`, `FORM_NA`, `FORM_PLAN`, `WELD_NA`, `WELD_PLAN`, `PAINT_NA`, `PAINT_PLAN`, `ASSY_START_PLAN`, `ASSY_START_ACTUAL`, `ASSY_START_BY`, `ASSY_START_SAVED_BY`, `ASSY_START_STARTED`, `REFRIG_NA`, `REFRIG_PLAN`, `REFRIG_ACTUAL`, `REFRIG_BY`, `REFRIG_SAVED_BY`, `ELECT_PLAN`, `ELECT_ACTUAL`, `ELECT_BY`, `ELECT_SAVED_BY`, `FINAL_PLAN`, `FINAL_ACTUAL`, `FINAL_BY`, `FINAL_SAVED_BY`, `TEST_PLAN`, `TEST_ACTUAL`, `TEST_BY`, `TEST_SAVED_BY`, `PREP_PLAN`, `PREP_ACTUAL`, `PREP_BY`, `PREP_SAVED_BY`, `SHIP_PLAN`, `SHIP_ACTUAL`, `SHIP_BY`, `SHIP_SAVED_BY`, `SHIP_COMPLETED`, `ACTIVE`, `OM_NA`, `OM_PLAN`, `OM_ACTUAL`, `OM_BY`, `OM_SAVED_BY`, `QuickShip`, `Mat_Comment`, `Hours_Design`, `Hours_CAD`, `Truck_Date`, `PAUSE`, `SHIP_COMPLETE`, `Est_Cost`, `Avg_Cost`, `Commission`, `WO_Closed`, `Order_Notification_Sent`)

VALUES

('68065',   '21222383', '2',    'US60', '21222383', '2',    'CON',  'TX1',  '10/15/2012',   'TX1',  'ERV',  'ERVA8024AAD-LBBS40M-MNAMH0ABKX',   'EXT',  'FOBS', '1',    '0',    '0',    '10/19/2012',   'NEW FORT GAY K-8 SCHOOL',  '10/19/2012',   'MASON & BARRY INC',    '21222383-02',  '1',    '0',    '80485',    '09/27/2012',   '03/30/2012',   '1',    '01/30/2012',   '14',   '10/19/2012',   '13',   '39',   '09/20/2012',   NULL,   '9',    '34',   '22',   '67',   '67',   '76',   '0',    '0',    '01/31/2012',   '01/31/2012',   '0',    '01/30/2012',   '01/30/2012',   '9',    '0',    '01/31/2012',   '138',  '138',  '0',    '02/01/2012',   '02/07/2012',   '1',    '1',    '0',    '02/14/2012',   '02/07/2012',   '02/29/2012',   '08/14/2012',   '1',    '08/22/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    '08/22/2012',   '08/22/2012',   '34',   '52',   '0',    '09/06/2012',   '09/10/2012',   '67',   '67',   '0',    '09/26/2012',   '10/26/2012',   '10',   '10',   '0',    '09/26/2012',   '09/10/2012',   '67',   '67',   '0',    '09/26/2012',   '09/26/2012',   '144',  '144',  '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '10/01/2012',   '10/01/2012',   '3',    '3',    '0',    '0',    '10/03/2012',   '10/03/2012',   '3',    '3',    '10/09/2012',   '10/09/2012',   '3',    '3',    '10/10/2012',   '10/11/2012',   '3',    '3',    '10/11/2012',   '10/17/2012',   '129',  '129',  '10/02/2012',   '10/02/2012',   '3',    '3',    '10/15/2012',   '10/19/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    '0',    '10/09/2012',   '41190',    '34',   '34',   '0',    'KAREL PO#142083',  NULL,   NULL,   '10/19/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   '51387',    NULL,   '0',    '1',    '1'),
('68067',   '21222383', '1',    'US60', '21222383', '1',    'CON',  'TX1',  '10/11/2012',   'TX1',  'ERV',  'ERVA1230AAD-LBBS60M-MNAMH0ABKX',   'EXT',  'FOBS', '1',    '0',    '0',    '10/19/2012',   'NEW FORT GAY K-8 SCHOOL',  '10/19/2012',   'MASON & BARRY INC',    '21222383-01',  '1',    '0',    '127834',   '09/25/2012',   '03/30/2012',   '1',    '01/30/2012',   '14',   '10/19/2012',   '13',   '138',  '08/20/2012',   NULL,   '9',    '34',   '22',   '96',   '96',   '76',   '0',    '0',    '01/31/2012',   '01/31/2012',   '0',    '01/30/2012',   '01/30/2012',   '9',    '0',    '01/31/2012',   '138',  '138',  '0',    '02/01/2012',   '02/07/2012',   '1',    '1',    '0',    '02/14/2012',   '02/07/2012',   '02/29/2012',   '08/14/2012',   '1',    '08/22/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    '08/21/2012',   '08/22/2012',   '34',   '52',   '0',    '09/05/2012',   '09/05/2012',   '96',   '96',   '0',    '09/25/2012',   '09/25/2012',   '10',   '10',   '0',    '09/25/2012',   '09/05/2012',   '96',   '96',   '0',    '09/25/2012',   '09/25/2012',   '144',  '144',  '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '09/27/2012',   '09/26/2012',   '3',    '3',    '0',    '0',    '10/02/2012',   '10/02/2012',   '3',    '3',    '10/04/2012',   '10/04/2012',   '3',    '3',    '10/08/2012',   '10/09/2012',   '3',    '3',    '10/09/2012',   '10/17/2012',   '129',  '129',  '10/01/2012',   '10/01/2012',   '3',    '3',    '10/11/2012',   '10/19/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    '0',    '10/08/2012',   '41190',    '34',   '34',   '0',    'KAREL PO#141865',  NULL,   NULL,   '10/19/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   '75072',    NULL,   '0',    '1',    '1'),
('68068',   '21222383', '3',    'US60', '21222383', '3',    'CON',  'TX1',  '10/11/2012',   'TX1',  'HCU',  'HCUB-10044-SMBN-00000-1100FSM',    'EXT',  'FOBS', '1',    '0',    '0',    '10/19/2012',   'NEW FORT GAY K-8 SCHOOL',  '10/19/2012',   'MASON & BARRY INC',    '21222383-03',  '1',    '0',    '13211',    '10/01/2012',   '03/30/2012',   '3',    '01/30/2012',   '14',   '10/19/2012',   '13',   '39',   '09/11/2012',   NULL,   '9',    '1',    NULL,   '112',  '112',  NULL,   '0',    '0',    '01/31/2012',   '01/31/2012',   '0',    '01/30/2012',   '01/30/2012',   '9',    '0',    '01/31/2012',   '138',  '138',  '0',    '02/01/2012',   '02/07/2012',   '1',    '1',    '0',    '02/14/2012',   '02/07/2012',   '02/29/2012',   '08/14/2012',   '1',    '08/22/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    '09/28/2012',   '08/28/2012',   '1',    '1',    '0',    '09/11/2012',   '09/05/2012',   '112',  '112',  '1',    '10/01/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    '10/01/2012',   '10/01/2012',   '112',  '112',  '1',    '10/01/2012',   '10/01/2012',   '144',  '144',  '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '10/03/2012',   '10/03/2012',   '64',   '64',   '0',    '1',    '10/04/2012',   '10/04/2012',   '64',   '64',   '10/09/2012',   '10/09/2012',   '64',   '64',   '10/10/2012',   '10/09/2012',   '64',   '64',   '10/11/2012',   '10/11/2012',   '129',  '129',  '10/03/2012',   '10/03/2012',   '64',   '64',   '10/11/2012',   '10/19/2012',   '129',  '129',  '10/12/2012',   '0',    '0',    '10/03/2012',   '41193',    '1',    '1',    '0',    'KAREL PO#131873',  NULL,   NULL,   '10/19/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   '9210', NULL,   '0',    '1',    '1'),
('67971',   '21222397', '2',    'US60', '21222397', '2',    'CON',  'TX1',  '03/21/2012',   'TX1',  'HCU',  'HCUC3415AAB-B0CS20M-MC0S00CAA0',   'EXT',  'FOBS', '1',    '0',    '0',    '03/26/2012',   'SUMMER PLACE', '03/26/2012',   'HEAT TRANSFER SOLUTIONS INC.', '21222397-02',  '1',    '0',    '38081',    '03/12/2012',   '01/27/2012',   '3',    '01/25/2012',   '10',   '03/26/2012',   '15',   '138',  '03/19/2012',   NULL,   '130',  '17',   '22',   '67',   '67',   NULL,   '1',    '0',    '01/26/2012',   '01/26/2012',   '0',    '01/25/2012',   '01/25/2012',   '130',  '0',    '01/26/2012',   '138',  '138',  '1',    '01/30/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    '02/09/2012',   '02/09/2012',   '02/09/2012',   '02/09/2012',   '1',    '02/21/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    '01/30/2012',   '01/27/2012',   '17',   '17',   '0',    '02/21/2012',   '02/21/2012',   '67',   '67',   '1',    '03/12/2012',   NULL,   '67',   '67',   '0',    '03/12/2012',   '02/21/2012',   '67',   '67',   '1',    '03/12/2012',   '03/12/2012',   '144',  '73',   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '03/14/2012',   '03/14/2012',   '64',   '64',   '1',    '1',    '03/15/2012',   '03/15/2012',   '64',   '64',   '03/19/2012',   '03/15/2012',   '64',   '64',   '03/20/2012',   '03/15/2012',   '64',   '64',   '03/21/2012',   '03/19/2012',   '129',  '129',  '03/14/2012',   '03/14/2012',   '64',   '64',   '03/21/2012',   '03/26/2012',   '129',  '129',  '03/21/2012',   '0',    '0',    '03/14/2012',   '40973',    '17',   '17',   '0',    'KAREL PO #132007', NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '25177',    NULL,   '0',    '1',    '1'),
('69706',   '21223341', '2',    'US60', '21223341', '2',    'CON',  'TX1',  '09/12/2012',   'TX1',  'HCU',  'DDXC6030AAD-A0BG804-KNCNE00AA5',   'EXT',  'FOBS', '1',    '0',    '0',    '10/05/2012',   'WAL*MART STORES INC. STORE # 5763',    '10/05/2012',   'WAL*MART STORES INC.', '21223341-02',  '1',    '0',    '34335',    '08/30/2012',   '10/05/2012',   '3',    '04/12/2012',   '16',   '10/05/2012',   '14',   '96',   '07/23/2012',   NULL,   '70',   '34',   NULL,   '112',  '112',  NULL,   '1',    '0',    '04/16/2012',   '04/16/2012',   '0',    '04/12/2012',   '04/10/2012',   '70',   '0',    '04/13/2012',   '138',  '138',  '1',    '04/17/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    '05/01/2012',   '05/01/2012',   '05/01/2012',   '05/01/2012',   '1',    '05/09/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    '07/30/2012',   '07/30/2012',   '34',   '34',   '0',    '08/13/2012',   '08/13/2012',   '112',  '112',  '1',    '08/30/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    '08/30/2012',   '08/30/2012',   '112',  '112',  '1',    '08/30/2012',   '08/30/2012',   '144',  '144',  '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '09/05/2012',   '09/05/2012',   '64',   '64',   '0',    '1',    '09/06/2012',   '09/06/2012',   '64',   '64',   '09/10/2012',   '09/06/2012',   '64',   '64',   '09/11/2012',   '09/10/2012',   '64',   '64',   '09/12/2012',   '09/11/2012',   '129',  '129',  '09/05/2012',   '09/05/2012',   '64',   '64',   '09/12/2012',   '10/05/2012',   '129',  '129',  '09/11/2012',   '0',    '0',    '09/05/2012',   '41156',    '34',   '34',   '0',    'EPMP PO#140794',   NULL,   NULL,   '10/05/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   '20601',    NULL,   '0',    '1',    '1'),
('69723',   '21223342', '1',    'US60', '21223342', '1',    'CON',  'TX1',  '07/05/2012',   'TX1',  'HCU',  'HCUC8040AAD-A0BG804-KC0NEAGAB0',   'EXT',  'FOBS', '1',    '0',    '0',    '07/09/2012',   'WAL*MART STORES INC. STORE # 3298',    '07/09/2012',   'WAL*MART STORES INC.', '21223342-01',  '1',    '0',    '66740',    '06/25/2012',   '07/09/2012',   '3',    '04/13/2012',   '14',   '07/09/2012',   '17',   '39',   '05/14/2012',   NULL,   '70',   '34',   NULL,   '112',  '112',  NULL,   '1',    '0',    '04/16/2012',   '04/16/2012',   '0',    '04/12/2012',   '04/10/2012',   '70',   '0',    '04/13/2012',   '138',  '138',  '1',    '04/17/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    '05/01/2012',   '05/01/2012',   '05/01/2012',   '05/01/2012',   '1',    '05/09/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    '05/21/2012',   '05/03/2012',   '34',   '34',   '0',    '06/05/2012',   '06/04/2012',   '112',  '112',  '1',    '06/25/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    '06/25/2012',   '06/25/2012',   '112',  '112',  '1',    '06/25/2012',   '06/25/2012',   '144',  '73',   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '06/27/2012',   '06/28/2012',   '64',   '64',   '0',    '1',    '06/28/2012',   '06/28/2012',   '64',   '64',   '07/02/2012',   '06/28/2012',   '64',   '64',   '07/03/2012',   '06/29/2012',   '64',   '64',   '07/05/2012',   '07/02/2012',   '129',  '129',  '06/27/2012',   '06/28/2012',   '64',   '64',   '07/05/2012',   '07/09/2012',   '129',  '129',  '07/05/2012',   '0',    '0',    '06/27/2012',   '41067',    '34',   '34',   '0',    'EPMP DUE DATE 6/25/2012 PO 137329',    NULL,   NULL,   '07/09/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   '40044',    NULL,   '0',    '1',    '1'),
('69724',   '21223342', '2',    'US60', '21223342', '2',    'CON',  'TX1',  '07/05/2012',   'TX1',  'HCU',  'HCUC6030AAD-A0BG804-KQ0NEAGAB0',   'EXT',  'FOBS', '1',    '0',    '0',    '07/09/2012',   'WAL*MART STORES INC. STORE # 3298',    '07/09/2012',   'WAL*MART STORES INC.', '21223342-02',  '1',    '0',    '53234',    '06/25/2012',   '07/09/2012',   '3',    '04/13/2012',   '14',   '07/09/2012',   '16',   '39',   '06/25/2012',   NULL,   '70',   '34',   NULL,   '112',  '112',  NULL,   '1',    '0',    '04/16/2012',   '04/16/2012',   '0',    '04/12/2012',   '04/10/2012',   '70',   '0',    '04/13/2012',   '138',  '138',  '1',    '04/17/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    '05/01/2012',   '05/01/2012',   '05/01/2012',   '05/01/2012',   '1',    '05/09/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    '05/17/2012',   '05/03/2012',   '34',   '34',   '0',    '06/04/2012',   '06/04/2012',   '112',  '112',  '1',    '06/21/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    '06/21/2012',   '06/25/2012',   '112',  '112',  '1',    '06/25/2012',   '06/25/2012',   '144',  '73',   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '06/26/2012',   '06/27/2012',   '64',   '64',   '0',    '1',    '06/27/2012',   '06/28/2012',   '64',   '64',   '06/28/2012',   '06/28/2012',   '64',   '64',   '07/02/2012',   '06/28/2012',   '64',   '64',   '07/03/2012',   '07/02/2012',   '129',  '129',  '06/26/2012',   '06/27/2012',   '64',   '64',   '07/03/2012',   '07/09/2012',   '129',  '129',  '07/05/2012',   '0',    '0',    '06/26/2012',   '41067',    '34',   '34',   '0',    'EPMP DUE DATE 6/25/2012 PO#137335',    NULL,   NULL,   '07/09/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   '31940',    NULL,   '0',    '1',    '1'),
('69728',   '21223344', '1',    'US60', '21223344', '1',    'CON',  'TX1',  '07/18/2012',   'TX1',  'HCU',  'HCUC5018AAD-CBBS151-HMBNE00BA0',   'EXT',  'FOBS', '1',    '0',    '0',    '07/19/2012',   'WAL*MART STORES INC. STORE # 1785',    '07/19/2012',   'WAL*MART STORES INC.', '21223344-01',  '1',    '0',    '36408',    '07/09/2012',   '07/19/2012',   '3',    '04/13/2012',   '15',   '07/19/2012',   '18',   '39',   '07/03/2012',   NULL,   '70',   '17',   NULL,   '112',  '112',  NULL,   '1',    '0',    '04/16/2012',   '04/16/2012',   '0',    '04/12/2012',   '04/10/2012',   '70',   '0',    '04/13/2012',   '138',  '138',  '1',    '04/17/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    '05/01/2012',   '05/01/2012',   '05/01/2012',   '05/01/2012',   '1',    '05/09/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    '05/31/2012',   '05/25/2012',   '17',   '17',   '0',    '06/14/2012',   '06/18/2012',   '112',  '112',  '1',    '07/05/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '0',    '07/05/2012',   '07/02/2012',   '112',  '112',  '1',    '07/05/2012',   '07/05/2012',   '72',   '73',   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '0',    NULL,   '07/10/2012',   '07/10/2012',   '64',   '64',   '0',    '1',    '07/11/2012',   '07/11/2012',   '64',   '64',   '07/12/2012',   '07/11/2012',   '64',   '64',   '07/16/2012',   '07/12/2012',   '64',   '64',   '07/17/2012',   '07/13/2012',   '129',  '129',  '07/10/2012',   '07/10/2012',   '64',   '64',   '07/17/2012',   '07/20/2012',   '129',  '129',  '07/16/2012',   '0',    '0',    '07/10/2012',   '41073',    '17',   '17',   '0',    'EPMP PO 138003 DUE DATE 7/5/2012', NULL,   NULL,   '07/19/2012',   NULL,   NULL,   '21844.8',  NULL,   '0',    '1',    '1')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - how many rows can I insert in one single INSERT statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536103/mysql-how-many-rows-can-i-insert-in-one-single-insert-statement)

Comment: No. I set my max_allowed_packets to a very high limit.

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. What did you set it to? Also, did you take note of this - *"Both the client and the server have their own max_allowed_packet variable, so if you want to handle big packets, you must increase this variable both in the client and in the server."*

Comment: Because it's a syntax error, I suspect that the query that's being generated is malformed somewhere in the middle.  The number of lines is probably a red herring.  You will likely need to dump the query into a text editor and validate that everything is properly quoted and escaped.  Look for quotes and other special characters which can mess up the query.  If you can post a gist of the full query, that's helpful too.

Comment: @Phil I apologize. If i were to list every single thing I did it would not fit in the allotted textarea. I found the problem. My php.ini file was set **max_file_uploads=20** when I changed that to 200, it worked fine. Thank you all for looking into this.