# Stored Procedure is taking more time to execute

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am executing a stored procedure im MYSQL. That will generate 6000 records and insert that 6000 records into a Table. For this, that stored procedure is taking more than 45 min.The file size of stored procedure is 45kb. Systems RAM is 0.98GB.
Does system RAM affecting the stored procedure performance?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sample`()
BEGIN

Declare FY_LHS Varchar(20); 
Declare FY_RHS Varchar(20); 

Declare abc int default 0; 
Declare bcd varchar(40) default null; 
Declare cde int default 0; 
Declare def varchar(40) default null; 
Declare efg int default 0; 
Declare ghi varchar(40) default null; 
Declare ijk varchar(40) default null;
Declare hij varchar(40) default null;
Declare ijk varchar(40) default null;
Declare param_month int ;


Declare monthsortsequence int default 0; 
Declare p int default 0;
Declare q int default 0; 
Declare r int default 0; 
Declare s int default 0; 
Declare t int default 0;  



DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
declare dateofdisch int default 0;
Declare fId int default 0; 
DECLARE fac_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT r FROM u ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

SET param_month = Month(CURDATE());

IF param_month = 4 THEN SET monthsortsequence = 1;
ELSEIF param_month = 5 THEN SET monthsortsequence = 2;
ELSEIF param_month = 6 THEN SET monthsortsequence = 3;
ELSEIF param_month = 7 THEN SET monthsortsequence = 4;
ELSEIF param_month = 8 THEN SET monthsortsequence = 5;
ELSEIF param_month = 9 THEN SET monthsortsequence = 6;
ELSEIF param_month = 10 THEN SET monthsortsequence = 7;
ELSEIF param_month = 11 THEN SET monthsortsequence = 8;
ELSEIF param_month = 12 THEN SET monthsortsequence = 9;
ELSEIF param_month = 1 THEN SET monthsortsequence = 10;
ELSEIF param_month = 2 THEN SET monthsortsequence = 11;
ELSEIF param_month = 3 THEN SET monthsortsequence = 12;
END IF;

  OPEN fac_cur;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH fac_cur INTO fId;
    IF fId >= 65 THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    IF fId != 0 THEN

IF MONTH(CURDATE())>=4 THEN
         Set FY_LHS = YEAR(CURDATE());
        Set FY_RHS = YEAR(CURDATE())+1;
ELSE 
        Set FY_LHS = YEAR(CURDATE())-1;
        Set FY_RHS = YEAR(CURDATE());
        END IF;


Select tblbc.StateId, tblst.StateName, tblbc.DistrictId, 
tblst.District, tblbc.kID, tblst.k, tblbc.FacilityName, tblbc.FacilityType, 
tblbc.ReportingToId  
into abc, bcd, cde, def, efg, ghi, ijk, hij, ijk  
from u tblbc inner join tblstateinfo tblst on 
tblbc.stateid = tblst.stateid and tblbc.DistrictId = tblst.dcode and tblbc.kID = tblst.tcode 
where tblbc.r = fId;

Delete from data where Year = concat(FY_LHS,'-',FY_RHS) and Month = param_month and r = fId;

Set p = (select count(*) as Count from w tblreg inner join tblp1s tblu on tblreg.p1id = tblu.p1id where tblreg.pm  = 0 and (Str_To_Date(tblreg.ty, '%d/%m/%Y') between Str_To_Date(concat(FY_LHS,'/04/01'), '%Y/%m/%d') and Str_To_Date(concat(FY_RHS,'/03/31'), '%Y/%m/%d')) and month(Str_To_Date(tblreg.ty, '%d/%m/%Y')) = param_month and tblu.r = fId); 
Set q = (Select count(ytid) as Count From w reg inner join tblp1s tblu on reg.p1id = tblu.p1Id where datediff(CurDate(), Str_To_Date(reg.LMP, '%d/%m/%Y')) < 300 and reg.pm = 0 and (Str_To_Date(reg.ty, '%d/%m/%Y') between Str_To_Date(concat(FY_LHS,'/04/01'), '%Y/%m/%d') and Str_To_Date(concat(FY_RHS,'/03/31'), '%Y/%m/%d')) and month(Str_To_Date(reg.ty, '%d/%m/%Y')) = param_month and tblu.r = fId); 
Set r = (Select count(reg.ytid) from (Select ts.p1id, ts.ytid, count(ts.ytid) as count from tblhjlist ts where ts.fgtype = 'ANC' and ts.actualdateofaction is not null and (Str_To_Date(actualdateofaction, '%d/%m/%Y') between Str_To_Date(concat(FY_LHS,'/04/01'), '%Y/%m/%d') and Str_To_Date(concat(FY_RHS,'/03/31'), '%Y/%m/%d')) and month(Str_To_Date(actualdateofaction, '%d/%m/%Y')) = param_month group by ts.ytid, ts.p1id) tss left join w reg on tss.ytid = reg.ytid inner join tblp1s tblu on reg.p1Id = tblu.p1id where tss.count = 3 and tblu.r = fId); 
Set s = (Select count(sl.ytid) from (Select p1id, ytid from tblhjlist where fgid = 1 and fgtype = 'FT' and actualdateofaction is not null and (Str_To_Date(actualdateofaction, '%d/%m/%Y') between Str_To_Date(concat(FY_LHS,'/04/01'), '%Y/%m/%d') and Str_To_Date(concat(FY_RHS,'/03/31'), '%Y/%m/%d')) and month(Str_To_Date(actualdateofaction, '%d/%m/%Y')) = param_month) sl inner join w reg on sl.ytid = reg.ytid inner join tblp1s tblu on reg.p1id = tblu.p1id and reg.pm = 0 and  tblu.r = fId); 
Set t = (Select count(ts.ytid) from (Select p1id, ytid from tblhjlist where ((fgtype = 'FT' and fgid = 2) or (fgtype = 'FTBooster' and fgid = 3)) and actualdateofaction is not null and (Str_To_Date(actualdateofaction, '%d/%m/%Y') between Str_To_Date(concat(FY_LHS,'/04/01'), '%Y/%m/%d') and Str_To_Date(concat(FY_RHS,'/03/31'), '%Y/%m/%d')) and month(Str_To_Date(actualdateofaction, '%d/%m/%Y')) = 9 group by ytid) ts inner join w reg on ts.ytid = reg.ytid inner join tblp1s tblu on reg.p1Id = tblu.p1Id and reg.pm = 0 and tblu.r = fId); 
.
.
.
.
.
40 queries

insert into data (year, month, stateId, state, districtId, district, kid, k, facilityname, facilityType, sortsequenceMonth, r, sortsequence, itemRefno, itemvalue, ReportingToId) values (concat(FY_LHS,'-',FY_RHS), param_month, abc, bcd, cde, def, efg, ghi, ijk, hij, monthsortsequence, fId, 2, '1.1.1', q, ijk);
insert into data (year, month, stateId, state, districtId, district, kid, k, facilityname, facilityType, sortsequenceMonth, r, sortsequence, itemRefno, itemvalue, ReportingToId) values (concat(FY_LHS,'-',FY_RHS), param_month, abc, bcd, cde, def, efg, ghi, ijk, hij, monthsortsequence, fId, 1, '1.1', p, ijk);
insert into data (year, month, stateId, state, districtId, district, kid, k, facilityname, facilityType, sortsequenceMonth, r, sortsequence, itemRefno, itemvalue, ReportingToId) values (concat(FY_LHS,'-',FY_RHS), param_month, abc, bcd, cde, def, efg, ghi, ijk, hij, monthsortsequence, fId, 3, '1.3', r, ijk);
insert into data (year, month, stateId, state, districtId, district, kid, k, facilityname, facilityType, sortsequenceMonth, r, sortsequence, itemRefno, itemvalue, ReportingToId) values (concat(FY_LHS,'-',FY_RHS), param_month, abc, bcd, cde, def, efg, ghi, ijk, hij, monthsortsequence, fId, 4, '1.4.1', s, ijk);
insert into data (year, month, stateId, state, districtId, district, kid, k, facilityname, facilityType, sortsequenceMonth, r, sortsequence, itemRefno, itemvalue, ReportingToId) values (concat(FY_LHS,'-',FY_RHS), param_month, abc, bcd, cde, def, efg, ghi, ijk, hij, monthsortsequence, fId, 5, '1.4.2', t, ijk);
.
.
.
.
40 insert statements

set fId = fId + 1;

 END IF;
  END LOOP;

CLOSE fac_cur;
END
```

Comment: show your code,that what you have done

Comment: Hi Jordan,that is not the complete code....it looks exactly like that

Comment: That's a lot of inserts you might want to google mysql insert limit and have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536103/mysql-how-many-rows-can-i-insert-in-one-single-insert-statement

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to check which statement exactly in the stored procedure
   is taking time by adding some debug points (ex: You can insert
   timestamp after each select into some temp table).
2. You need to check that you have proper indexes on table for select
   queries.